# Android Gradle - task overwrite is not working

Tags: android, gradle, task, robotium-recorder

I am really confused as to why this overwrite is not working.

I made a project by robotium record .when I sync this project ,android studio told me an error log as following.

`Gradle 'EpayAppTest' project refresh failed
Error:Cannot add task ':EpayAppTest:assembleDebug' as a task with that name already exists.`

Is there anything wrong with my build.gradle ,whitch is generated by Robotium Recorder.

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    android {
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        sourceSets
                {
                    androidTest
                            {
                                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                            }
                }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}

task assembleDebug( overwrite: true) {}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'E:/work/app-qa-debug-withTest_debug.apk'
    into 'build/outputs/apk/'
    rename {
        'EpayAppTest-debug.apk'
    }
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn copyTask
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in version 2.5.0. Please update Robotium Recorder through Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try bringing the following to the top of the script, see if that works...

```
dependencies {
androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Tried ,but failed. As throwed another error: Error:(16, 0) Could not find method androidTestCompile() for arguments [com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.